# How to configure that specific files should go to different remotes with DVC?

Tags: dvc

I'd like to have these remotes (from `.dvc/config`):

```
['remote "test-data"']
    url = gs://some-test-bucket/dvc
['remote "prod-data"']
    url = gs://some-prod-bucket/dvc
```

(I have not set a default remote.)

And I have some test data in the folder `./test-data`, and production data in the folder ./prod-data.

The .dvc file for prod data:

```
$ cat prod-data.dvc
outs:
- md5: 057682599b100f0240ca51b6256ed7d5.dir
  size: 135840994497
  nfiles: 17008
  hash: md5
  path: prod-data
```

Example of .dvc file for test data:

```
$ cat test-data/some_folder.dvc
outs:
- md5: c06520abe0140c72004dbe4494a78b23.dir
  size: 692847854
  nfiles: 8
  hash: md5
  path: some_folder
```

I want the command `dvc pull -r prod-data` to only give me the `./prod-data/` folder, but instead it's fetching more:

```
$ dvc pull -r prod-data
A       prod-data/
A       test-data/some_folder/
A       test-data/some_other_folder_entirely/
3 files added
```

How can I set this up so that the test files are stored in one remote, while the prod data is stored in another? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how DVC should be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup `dvc pull -r prod-data` and `dvc push -r prod-data` try to pull / push *all* data (*all* `.dvc` files). Unless you explicitly specify a target: `dvc pull -r test-data test-data/some_folder`.

To actually split data by a few remotes, you need to use the [remote field](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvc-files):

```yaml
outs:
- md5: c06520abe0140c72004dbe4494a78b23.dir
  size: 692847854
  nfiles: 8
  hash: md5
  path: some_folder
  remote: test-data
```

At the moment, I don't think it can be specified as part of the `dvc add` command that creates the `.dvc` files for you. It's expected that you manage this (and some other fields) manually.

After it's done, you won't need also to keep specifying `-r` on `dvc pull` / `dvc push`. It will pick this automatically.

Please, give it a try and let me know if you hit some issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have an example reference-data.dvc file where I've added the `remote` field, specifying "reference-data" as the value. However, when I run `dvc pull -r test-data`, then that reference-data.dvc data is still being pulled. Even though that .dvc file is specifically specified to belong to the reference-data remote. I believe this happens because the test-data remote wrongly also contains the data that's in the reference-data.dvc file. However, even so, I don't want that pull to happen because I'm only interested in the test-data. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need to use `-r` at all in that case. I need to check, but I think `-r test-data` would override all the named remotes. The semantics of `-r` overall is to override the remote that is being used by default. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you want to have a command to pull only a specific subset of files / directories? only those that belong to a certain remote?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wish to pull all files belonging to a specific remote, without having to manually find those .dvc files and pull them explicitly.

Comment: Please see / comment here https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/8298 . I don't this this exact behavior is possible with CLI. You could try to use DVC internal API:

```
import os
from dvc.repo import Repo
repo = Repo()
outs = [
    os.path.relpath(out.fs_path, repo.root_dir)
    for out in repo.index.outs 
    if out.remote == "storage"
]
repo.pull(outs, allow_missing=True)
```